# Navigation tabs missing on /questions page due to custom question lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, custom-question-lists

I noticed that the tabs/controlls on the `/questions` pages are gone on MSE, MSO and SE:

[image: No tabs]

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions

They are still there on other sites:

[image: There are tabs]

- https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions

This - and because I opted in for CQL beta - is why I suppose that this is related to custom question lists.

<sub>Originally posted in chat by me</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the report; fix is being tested now

Comment: @Shog9 great, I am seeing the standard /questions view now correctly but Filter>My watched tags is still not working correctly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?sort=Newest&tagMode=Watched

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. We just merged in a change to eliminate a bunch of `if/else` branches around unified theming and we missed an `@` symbol on the front of an ASP.NET MVC call to `Html.Partial`. It got missed in code review and we neglected to test this particular permutation while giving it a test run :(

Anyway, fix is on meta, and we're rolling build 2018.12.10.32364 out to prod now.

Comment: Yay, I would call this completed! (Did some little testing and :D)